# Read binary data from IoT hub using Spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, azure-iot-hub

I have IoT hub receiving binary data that I would like to read from a Spark streaming job. How do I read binary data from IoT hub?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since Azure IoT Hub has a Event Hub compatible endpoint that can be used to [read D2C message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-read-builtin)(if you suppose). You can find connection string in azure portal:

[image]

And here is [Azure Event Hubs Connector for Apache Spark](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark) you can have check to see if it helps.

**Update:**

If you want to process file data from Azure IoT Hub, the Spark Stream also support Azure Storage blob.

Ref: [Upload files with IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-file-upload), [Create Spark Streaming jobs with exactly-once event processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-streaming-exactly-once)